# Check pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I Have next pattern:
[a-z[A-Z]а-я[А-Я][0-9]їЇіІєЄ[-][,]_"/\ ]{0,483}

```
<input
 id="<?= $field['id'];?>"
 name="input"                       
 <?php if (isset($field['regex'])) echo "pattern=".$field['regex'];?>
>
```

By this pattern I check data in field by javascript:

```
var decode_pattern = $(this).attr('pattern');
var reg = RegExp("^" + decode_pattern + "$");
```

But when i try to input (sdfzsdf) in field, regexp tell me - wrong.

Why?

Comment: You put the validation pattern directly in the markup? This just doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ChristopherW — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute

Comment: @Quentin, fancy! Check my box for learning something new today.

Comment: What's the result you get for `reg`?

Answer (score 1):

> I Have this pattern: `[a-z[A-Z]а-я[А-Я][0-9]їЇіІєЄ[-][,]_"/\ ]{0,483}`

JavaScript Regex syntax does't allow character classes in character classes. Maybe you meant

```
[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9їЇіІєЄ,_"/\\ -]{0,483}
```

Your current regex is equivalent to `/[a-z\[A-Z]а-я[А-Я]\dїЇіІєЄ-,_"\/ \]{0,483}/`.

Also, since it contains a quote you will need to html-escape your attribute value:

```
echo 'pattern="'.htmlspecialchars($field['regex']).'"';
```